# How do I scp files of size less than x?

Tags: command-line, scp

I am developing something on my laptop and scp'ing the files to a high performance PC (a server with no monitor). Out of laziness I just do this currently (on the laptop):

```
scp -r ~/project/* server:~/project/
```

However some of the files in the project directory are some log files and out files which I don't need to send, which can sometimes be a gig or so. What I would like is a nice clean command which basically does the same thing (transmits all the files in project and its subdirectories) but only sends files under a certain filesize threshold, such as 100 mb. I'm only mildly experienced with bash and not at all with regexp so I don't really have any idea how to do this without some convoluted method such as importing sys into python and using a bunch of ifs and comparisons.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can use 'rsync' command which has an option to controlling the file size to be excluding.

```
rsync -rv --max-size=100m /path/in/local/ server:~/project/
```

from '[man rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/rsync.1.html)',

```
--max-size=SIZE    don't transfer any file larger than SIZE
```

**Updated answer** : simply exclude the log files with 'rsync' --exclude option as below

```
rsync -rv --exclude='*.log' --max-size=100m /path/in/local/ server:~/project/
```

or you can use the 'find' command combination with 'scp' and specify the file size limit with its `-size` option. use `! -name '*.log'` to exclude the certain files end with 'log'.

```
find /path/in/local -type f ! -name '*.log' -size -100m -exec scp '{}' server:~/project/ \;
```

Comment: A note for the OP: `rsync` is similar to `scp`, but more efficient, as it transfers only changes if a file is modified.

Comment: ***be careful with the order of directories*** as `rsync -rv --max-size SOURCE DESTINATION`. I didn't read properly, and this coud have very bad consequences.